# Managing Content Type using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, content-type, api

How can i manage Content Type in SharePoint List using REST API, it's look like a very wide question, isn't it ? well what i'm looking for exactly is:

1. How to change content type visibility option to hidden
2. How to reorder content type

ps: All that using the REST API

Comment: Refer this link. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251300/hide-remove-contenttype-from-a-sp-list-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `contenttypes` REST API at `<<yoursiteurl>>/_api/web/contenttypes`. or for list-/library- level content types: `<<yoursiteurl>>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('teamlist')/contenttypes`

If you are attempting to create a new ContentType, make sure you specify the Id as defined sub-object in your `POST` Body.

```
{
    '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.ContentType'},
    'Description': 'TestDesc',
    'Name': 'ContentType New',
    'Group': 'Custom Group',        
    'Id':{
        '__metadata':{
            'type':'SP.ContentTypeId'
        },
        'StringValue':'0x01234567890'
    }
}
```

If you are updating an existing content type, perform your `PATCH` or `MERGE` with the ContentTypeID specified in the URI, such as:

`<<yoursiteurl>>_api/web/contenttypes('0x01234567890')`

To make the content type "Visible", set `Hidden` to `false`, to Hide it, set `Hidden` to `true`:

```
{
    '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.ContentType'},
    'Hidden': false,
}
```

To set the Content Type Order, you have to use the `uniqueContentTypeOrder` method on the `Folder` object API (note, this is an operation on the folder, not on the List.  While you can call `uniqueContentTypeOrder` on the List object, it is read-only on that object and will not accept any updates.
 Good: `<<yoursiteurl>>_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/ati-poc/Lists/TeamList')/uniqueContentTypeOrder`
 Bad (read-only): `<<yoursiteurl>>_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TeamList')/rootfolder/uniqueContentTypeOrder`

```
{
    "__metadata":{"type":"Collection(SP.ContentTypeId)"},
    "results":[
        {"StringValue":"0x01060095AA05C7EF742C4DB3F474F3C5212ACD"}, 
        {"StringValue":"0x0100873141339207DB4DA9397A3866FB9F1D"}
    ]
}
```

Be sure when updating to specify your content-type with `odata=verbose` and appropriate `if-match` and `x-http-method`:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": <<DigestValue>>,
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
}
```

Comment: These tips made my day! Following your samples I made a custom form setup. 